# Can we request for email from Twitter using oAuth in Android?

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, xauth, twitter-fabric

I have a requirement to request Twitter for the User's email. I came across the Twitter Fabric SDK that will retrieve the User's email ie; https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/request-email but for that our app has has to be whitelisted by Twitter and a special form needs to be filled ie; https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform . Could you please let me know if we need to select "I need access to special authentication privileges (e.g. xAuth)" in the form or can we get the email using oAuth only and how?

Thank you.

Comment: hi.. i am having the same issue.. did you find the solution of how to get android app white-listed in fabric?

Answer (score 1):

You do need to fill in the support form and specify that you want email address accessing using OAuth. Since the page does not current have an option for that, I'd use the xAuth button and enter in the details box that you do not need xAuth, you actually want elevated privileges to access email address. I'll see whether the support team can get the forms updated to make this more clear.